# colon disappear in the href link of http:// in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I created the wordpress sample plugin. Here is some code i struggle.

```
<?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=get_option('ptechsolcopy_times');$i++)
        {
            $find='http://';
            $pos=strpos(get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'.$i),$find);


            ?>
             <a href="<?php if($pos==0) { echo "http://".get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'.$i); } else {echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'.$i); } ?>" rel="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_follower'.$i); ?>"> <?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_name'.$i);  ?></a>
        <?php }
                ?>
```

I wonder to add the `http://` prefix to the href link but it display only the `http//` 
See this is the one that i created [image]

If i already using the http://google.com in the textbox it display `http//google.com` when i use google.com that http:// added perfectly .. I don't know what i did any suggestion would be great.Is i did anything wrong in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your code snippet you verify that the link starts with http://, then concatenates the link to another http:// in your anchor tag. (`echo "http://".get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'.$i);`

Look at the source code of your page, you may find that your link looks like this: `http://http://google.com` which shows up in the browser as `http//google.com`